# To list the azure VMs associated with a specific key vault?

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

How to import the list of Azure Vm's associated with the specific key vault through powershell?

Comment: Hi,Have you tried any powershell script? if so please edit  the question with powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

I tested for only one resource group with the below PowerShell script, so you can remove the resource group it will show all the VM's for the subscription.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$vaultname="your KeyVault name"
$virtualmachines=Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "your resource group name"
$vm=@()
foreach ($virtualmachine in $virtualmachines) {
$sp = Get-AzADServicePrincipal -displayname $virtualmachine.Name
$id=$sp.Id
$keyvault= Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $vaultname -ResourceGroupName "your resource group name"
$obj=$keyvault.AccessPolicies.ObjectId
if ($obj -eq $sp.Id){
$deviceprops = [ordered] @{
VMDisplayName = $sp.DisplayName
}
$deviceobj = new-object -Type PSObject -Property $deviceprops
$vm += $deviceobj
}
}
$vm
$vm | Export-CSV "C:\VMNames.csv"
```

**Outputs.**

[image]

[image]